# Is there any limit on number or size of DOM event listeners registered by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on web application that needs to define therapy steps. Each therapy step can consist of up to three phases: preparation, main and finish, where main is mandatory and preparation and finish are optional. For time recording purposes I need to define for each phase minimum, standard and maximum duration of the phase, which leads to 9 inputs from user side. I want to make it visual, so that user can play with resizeable bars to set-up needed times.

I'm using html and JavaScript, but application itself is written in Yii (basically php, JavaScript, database). My target platform is Firefox and maybe Google Chrome, IE is not considered to be supported at all.

I came across a [blog](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/) that makes possible to make div element to fire some resize events as this is not supported by browsers. I played with jsfiddle to create such visual interpretation that changes values in input boxes and should check size/duration of min and max comparing to standard (so that i don't end up with minimum longer than standard or maximum shorter than standard duration). what puzzles me now is that even after playing around, I cannot make it working on all three phases. The preparation phase works as intended in FireFox, but main and finish phase are not, in main only resize to input box works(filling in value as result of resize) and finish does not work at all. I even tried firebug to find problem but end up helpless, as I see no indication of any error. I am thinking if there is any limit on number of function that can be registered as event handlers or their size(of code)? Of course there could be some error in JavaScript I worked out so far, but after spending so many nights I do not see them probably.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<p>Step definition</p>
<p> <pre>
Priprava
Min:<input id='input1min' name='phase1_min' value='39' />
Std:<input id='input1std' value='39' />
Max:<input id='input1max' value='39' />
    </pre>

</p>
<div id="wrap_prep" class="horizontal" align="left" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="wrap_prep_max" class="horizontal max">MAX <span id="prep_max_val">39m</span>
        <ul id="prep_max" >
            <li style="color:rgb(255,0,0);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrap_prep_std" class="horizontal std">STD <span id="prep_std_val">39m</span>

        <ul id="prep_std">
            <li style="color:rgb(50,155,50);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrap_prep_min" class="horizontal min">MIN <span id="prep_min_val">39m</span>

        <ul id="prep_min">
            <li style="color:rgb(0,0,255);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <ul id="prep">
        <li style="color:white;">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;">Príprava &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p> <pre>
Vykon
Min:<input id='input2min' name='phase2_min' value='39' />
Std:<input id='input2std' value='39' />
Max:<input id='input2max' value='39' />
    </pre>

</p>
<div id="wrap_main" class="horizontal" align="left" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="wrap_main_max" class="horizontal max">MAX <span id="main_max_val">39m</span>
        <ul id="main_max">
            <li style="color:rgb(255,0,0);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrap_main_std" class="horizontal std">STD <span id="main_std_val">39m</span>
        <ul id="main_std">
            <li style="color:rgb(50,155,50);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrap_main_min" class="horizontal min">MIN <span id="main_min_val">39m</span>
        <ul id="main_min">
            <li style="color:rgb(0,0,255);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <ul id="main1">
        <li style="color:white;">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;">Výkon &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<p> <pre>
Ukoncenie
Min:<input id='input3min' name='phase3_min' value='39' />
Std:<input id='input3std' value='39' />
Max:<input id='input3max' value='39' />
    </pre>

</p>
<div id="wrap_fin" class="horizontal" align="left" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="wrap_fin_max" class="horizontal max">MAX <span id="fin_max_val">39m</span>
        <ul>
            <li id="fin_max" style="color:rgb(255,0,0);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrap_fin_std" class="horizontal std">STD <span id="fin_std_val">39m</span>
        <ul>
            <li id="fin_std" style="color:rgb(50,155,50);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="wrap_fin_min" class="horizontal min">MIN <span id="fin_min_val">39m</span>
        <ul>
            <li id="fin_min" style="color:rgb(0,0,255);">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li id="fin" style="color:white;">xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x x x x x x xx xxx x xxxxxx xxx xx x x xx x xxxxxx xx x x xxxxx x xx x xxxxxxx x x x x x xxx xxxx x xxx x x x</li>
    </ul>
    <p style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0;">Ukončenie &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//----------------resize magic----code---

function addFlowListener(element, type, fn) {
    var flow = type == 'over';
    element.addEventListener('OverflowEvent' in window ? 'overflowchanged' : type + 'flow', function (e) {
        if (e.type == (type + 'flow') || ((e.orient === 0 && e.horizontalOverflow == flow) || (e.orient == 1 && e.verticalOverflow == flow) || (e.orient == 2 && e.horizontalOverflow == flow && e.verticalOverflow == flow))) {
            e.flow = type;
            return fn.call(this, e);
        }
    }, false);
}

function fireEvent(element, type, data, options) {
    var options = options || {},
    event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent(type, 'bubbles' in options ? options.bubbles : true, 'cancelable' in options ? options.cancelable : true);
    for (var z in data) event[z] = data[z];
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function addResizeListener(element, fn) {
    var resize = 'onresize' in element;
    if (!resize && !element._resizeSensor) {
        var sensor = element._resizeSensor = document.createElement('div');
        sensor.className = 'resize-sensor';
        sensor.innerHTML = '<div class="resize-overflow"><div></div></div><div class="resize-underflow"><div></div></div>';

        var x = 0,
            y = 0,
            first = sensor.firstElementChild.firstChild,
            last = sensor.lastElementChild.firstChild,
            matchFlow = function (event) {
                var change = false,
                    width = element.offsetWidth;
                if (x != width) {
                    first.style.width = width - 1 + 'px';
                    last.style.width = width + 1 + 'px';
                    change = true;
                    x = width;
                }
                var height = element.offsetHeight;
                if (y != height) {
                    first.style.height = height - 1 + 'px';
                    last.style.height = height + 1 + 'px';
                    change = true;
                    y = height;
                }
                if (change && event.currentTarget != element) fireEvent(element, 'resize');
            };

        if (getComputedStyle(element).position == 'static') {
            element.style.position = 'relative';
            element._resizeSensor._resetPosition = true;
        }
        addFlowListener(sensor, 'over', matchFlow);
        addFlowListener(sensor, 'under', matchFlow);
        addFlowListener(sensor.firstElementChild, 'over', matchFlow);
        addFlowListener(sensor.lastElementChild, 'under', matchFlow);
        element.appendChild(sensor);
        matchFlow({});
    }
    var events = element._flowEvents || (element._flowEvents = []);
    if (events.indexOf(fn) == -1) events.push(fn);
    if (!resize) element.addEventListener('resize', fn, false);
    element.onresize = function (e) {
        events.forEach(function (fn) {
            fn.call(element, e);
        });
    };
}

function removeResizeListener(element, fn) {
    var index = element._flowEvents.indexOf(fn);
    if (index > -1) element._flowEvents.splice(index, 1);
    if (!element._flowEvents.length) {
        var sensor = element._resizeSensor;
        if (sensor) {
            element.removeChild(sensor);
            if (sensor._resetPosition) element.style.position = 'static';
            delete element._resizeSensor;
        }
        if ('onresize' in element) element.onresize = null;
        delete element._flowEvents;
    }
    element.removeEventListener('resize', fn);
}

//----------------resize magic----init---

var inp1min = document.getElementById('input1min');
var inp1std = document.getElementById('input1std');
var inp1max = document.getElementById('input1max');

var inp2min = document.getElementById('input2min');
var inp2std = document.getElementById('input2std');
var inp2max = document.getElementById('input2max');

var prep_std = document.getElementById('prep_std');
var prep_min = document.getElementById('prep_min');
var prep_max = document.getElementById('prep_max');
var prep_min_val = document.getElementById('prep_min_val');
var prep_std_val = document.getElementById('prep_std_val');
var prep_max_val = document.getElementById('prep_max_val');
var w_prep_std = document.getElementById('wrap_prep_std');
var w_prep_min = document.getElementById('wrap_prep_min');
var w_prep_max = document.getElementById('wrap_prep_max');
var w_prep = document.getElementById('wrap_prep');
var w_prep1 = document.getElementById('prep');

var main_std = document.getElementById('main_std');
var main_min = document.getElementById('main_min');
var main_max = document.getElementById('main_max');
var main_min_val = document.getElementById('main_min_val');
var main_std_val = document.getElementById('main_std_val');
var main_max_val = document.getElementById('main_max_val');
var w_main_std = document.getElementById('wrap_main_std');
var w_main_min = document.getElementById('wrap_main_min');
var w_main_max = document.getElementById('wrap_main_max');
var w_main = document.getElementById('wrap_main');
var w_main1 = document.getElementById('main1');

var fin_std = document.getElementById('fin_std');
var fin_min = document.getElementById('fin_min');
var fin_max = document.getElementById('fin_max');
var fin_min_val = document.getElementById('fin_min_val');
var fin_std_val = document.getElementById('fin_std_val');
var fin_max_val = document.getElementById('fin_max_val');
var w_fin_std = document.getElementById('wrap_fin_std');
var w_fin_min = document.getElementById('wrap_fin_min');
var w_fin_max = document.getElementById('wrap_fin_max');
var w_fin = document.getElementById('wrap_fin');
var w_fin1 = document.getElementById('fin');


function computeValue1(obj1) {
    return Math.round(obj1.offsetWidth / 10) - 2;
}

function updateInpValue(inp1, obj1, disp1) {
    var aval = computeValue1(obj1);
    inp1.value = (aval > 0 ? aval : "off");
    disp1.innerHTML = (aval > 0 ? aval + 'm' : "--");
}

function checkSizeMSM(wrap_min, wrap_std, wrap_max, wrap, wrap_content) {
    //check size MSM= Min Standard Max
    //due to css style we have border 3px and padding 2px on both sides this means offsetWidth is in total 10px more than style.width
    var correction = 10;
    var margin1 = 5;
    var min1 = wrap_min.offsetWidth;
    var std1 = wrap_std.offsetWidth;
    var max1 = wrap_max.offsetWidth;
    var wrap1 = wrap_content.offsetWidth;
    //console.log('check MSM, min1:'+min1+', std1:'+std1+', max1:'+max1+', wrap1:'+wrap1);
    if (min1 > std1) wrap_min.style.width = (std1 - correction) + 'px';
    if (std1 < min1) wrap_min.style.width = (std1 - correction) + 'px';
    if (max1 < std1) wrap_max.style.width = (std1 - correction) + 'px';
    if (std1 > max1) wrap_max.style.width = (std1 - correction) + 'px';
    if (max1 < wrap1 - correction - margin1) wrap.style.width = (max1 + correction + margin1) + 'px';
    if (max1 > wrap1) wrap.style.width = (max1 + correction + margin1) + 'px';
}

addResizeListener(prep_std, function (e) {
    //console.log(e);
    updateInpValue(inp1std, prep_std, prep_std_val);
    checkSizeMSM(w_prep_min, w_prep_std, w_prep_max, w_prep, w_prep1);
});
addResizeListener(prep_min, function (e) {
    updateInpValue(inp1min, prep_min, prep_min_val);
    checkSizeMSM(w_prep_min, w_prep_std, w_prep_max, w_prep, w_prep1);
});
addResizeListener(prep_max, function (e) {
    updateInpValue(inp1max, prep_max, prep_max_val);
    checkSizeMSM(w_prep_min, w_prep_std, w_prep_max, w_prep, w_prep1);
});


addResizeListener(main_std, function (e) {
    //console.log(e);
    updateInpValue(inp2std, main_std);
    checkSizeMSM(w_main_min, w_main_std, w_main_max, w_main, w_main1);
});
addResizeListener(main_min, function (e) {
    updateInpValue(inp2min, main_min);
    checkSizeMSM(w_main_min, w_main_std, w_main_max, w_main, w_main1);
});
addResizeListener(main_max, function (e) {
    updateInpValue(inp2max, main_max);
    checkSizeMSM(w_main_min, w_main_std, w_main_max, w_main, w_main1);
});


addResizeListener(fin_std, function (e) {
    //console.log(e);
    updateInpValue(inp3std, fin_std);
    checkSizeMSM(w_fin_min, w_fin_std, w_fin_max, w_fin, w_fin1);
});
addResizeListener(fin_min, function (e) {
    updateInpValue(inp3min, fin_min);
    checkSizeMSM(w_fin_min, w_fin_std, w_fin_max, w_fin, w_fin1);
});
addResizeListener(fin_max, function (e) {
    updateInpValue(inp3max, fin_max);
    checkSizeMSM(w_fin_min, w_fin_std, w_fin_max, w_fin, w_fin1);
});
```

**CSS**

```
   body {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#wrap {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
#list {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #CAE8F9;
}
.resize-sensor, .resize-sensor > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}
div.horizontal {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 463px;
    height: 150px;
    resize: horizontal;
    border: 3px solid rgb(222, 222, 222);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.max {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 450px;
    min-width: 55px;
    height: 20px;
    resize: horizontal;
    border: 3px solid rgb(222, 0, 0);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 0, 0);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.std {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 450px;
    min-width: 55px;
    height: 20px;
    resize: horizontal;
    border: 3px solid rgb(35, 122, 35);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(50, 155, 50);
    color: black;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.min {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 450px;
    min-width: 55px;
    height: 20px;
    resize: horizontal;
    border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 222);
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 255);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Or any idea of something that can provide me with such functionality I want to provide (visual setting of min,std,max times with resizable elements)? there could be also proposed solution in jQuery, I am not an expert in it, but will get through needed parts if it will work.

My current progress can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/vtXRQ/15/

Comment: Nope, no real limits on event handlers or size of code. it's more likely that you havea  logic error somewhere.

Comment: Have you considered using JQuery for this? It would take only a fraction of the code to do the same job (and generally works cross-browser without tweaking).

Comment: well I was trying to avoid jQuery originally, but it seems to be working much better. Thanks @TrueBlueAussie. The result of this can be found at  http://jsfiddle.net/n9tfn/3/